# How to parse HTML tags to text features in dijit.Editor?

Tags: html, dojo, formatting, editor

I have a `dijit.Editor` on the page.
If i type "example" and apply `bold` feature, it will look like "**example**". And the text I got from the editor is `<b>example</br>`.
But if I want to put bold text to the editor and set content to `<b>example</br>`, I can see 'example' in the editor field, not **example**.
I tried to set text via

```
new dijit.Editor({
    content: this.text
});
```

and

```
editor.execCommand("inserthtml", this.text);
```

Is there any way to make `dijit.Editor` parse all these tags to text features?

Comment: how do you set content?

Comment: sorry, forgot to put code. Check question.

Comment: As far as i'm aware there is editor.set("value", "<b>example</b>");, which dojo version you are using?

Comment: `editor.set("value", "text");` doesn't work at all.  I don't know exact dojo version, it should be about 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: ok, you can also try: var editor = new dijit.Editor({
    content: this.text
}); editor.setValue("<b>example</b>"); or editor.replaceValue("<b>example</b>");

Comment: None of this helps. I thinke there is a problem with dynamic content in widgets - everything is shown as plain text. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Well not sure, but i have no problem setting html to the editor, http://jsfiddle.net/VLPTj/

Comment: Why do you need `dojo.dom` and `dojo.domReady!`? Is it essential? Because I don't have such libraries.

Comment: It's not essential for example, http://jsfiddle.net/VLPTj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happened to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/16983545/1711975

Thanks everybody for help!