# HTML is shown as plain text in dojo widget

Tags: html, dojo, widget, plaintext

I have a dojo widget with generated content, text message in my case.
Message text is a formatted text with `<b>, <i>` etc. tags. When I put it to my widget via `${messageText}` it is shown as it is a plain text.

How to make my widget parse all these tags to DOM nodes?

**upd**
.jsp fragment:

```
<script>
(new MyWidget({
    text: "<b>message</b>"
}).placeAt(dojo.byId("placeWidgetHere");
</script>

<div id="placeWidgetHere"></div>
```

widget .html template:

```
<div>${text}</div>
```

Comment: I think your problem is somewhere else. I just tested it (Dojo 1.9) by creating a HTML widget and I can use HTML tags. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tLqWd/

Comment: what does `parser.parse()` do?

Comment: It converts the HTML code with the `data-dojo-type` to a widget. It's similar to the configuration option: `parseOnLoad: true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `messageText` has "<" and ">" symbols converted to "<" and ">" respectively.
I added `.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">")` to messageText and that began to work properly.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [substitution variables](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html#substitution-variables) (which is not recommended), you can use an [attribute map](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#mapping-widget-attributes-to-domnode-attributes) on your custom widget.

```
<div>
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="messageTextNode"></span>
</div>


declare('MyWidget'], [TemplatedMixin], {
    template: ...,

    messageText: '',
     _setMessageTextAttr: { node: "messageTextNode", type: "innerHTML" },
});

new MyWidget({
    messageText: "<b>message</b>"
}, "placeWidgetHere");
```

Comment: what is `_setMessageTextAttr`?

Comment: `_setXXXAttr` is a naming convention on widgets that when a widget is instantiated with a property named XXX, if a method named `_setXXXAttr` on the widget exists, it will be called. Otherwise the XXX value will be directly set onto the widget. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#custom-setters-getters